# Using a bunch of smartphones with headsets like collar microphones

Tags: microphone, smartphone

We are planning to put up a low-budget stage play shortly. For this instead of using the costly collar microphones I am looking at some possibilities of using smartphones (android) with headsets like collar microphones. Can someone suggest how I can go about that?

Comment: How are you going to get the audio from the smart phone to the PA system in the theater? If you're thinking of sending the audio over a network like a WiFi network or the Internet, I'm afraid you'll almost certainly encounter latency that is far too great to be workable. You should be able to rent a radio mic system. The other option is to have the actors project and make sure other noises are quieter.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I was actually thinking of doing it over a local WiFi network, but I understand the issues with latency. Renting out is costly in this part of the world, especially because this is for a non-profit charitable spiritual organisation. Thanks for your inputs!